Old Wooden Window Pane Replacement
I have some old double pane windows and one of the outside panes cracked recently. I would like to order the replacement window pane and put in myself, but haven’t found a good DIY video for old wooden windows like these. I assume I need to remove the wooden frame, attached are some pictures, there are small brass spring loaded balls. Are they holding the frames in place some how? If not what purpose do they serve?
https://imgur.com/a/asRrI0f

Please provide some properly focused photos. These hurt my eyes. Also, your title should be a clear, specific question. Please take the [tour].

imgur is an even greater time waster than SE.  please insert the images into your question.

Those look to me like removable wooden stops on the inside of the window.  Assuming that's true, then you would remove the stops, then the window glass can then be taken out and measured for replacement.  If not, then a lot of what I say below will not apply.
As far as how to remove the stops, that will take a little bit of investigation.  Perhaps those holes in the stops have screws in them to hold the stops in place?  If so, take those out.  There are also many layers of paint holding the stops to the window frame, so you will need to release that somehow.  A common way is to use a utility knife to cut through the paint right at the joint between stop and frame.  If done carefully, you might not even need to repaint when the repair is complete.  Some people might go to the trouble of stripping the paint to bare wood.  Others might just take a scraper and gouge away at the paint to release the stop from the frame.  You choose your weapon.
Even after all that, you will probably need to do some prying to get the stops off.  Use a putty knife or prybar to get the stops out.  It may be harder than you think to loosen up the stops for removal.  There could be nails holding them in place.
After the stops are out, then you need to get the glass out.  There will be paint on the outside gluing the glass in place.  A utility knife or razor blade scraper might help with that.
Once the glass is out and measured, any window shop should be able to produce the right size glass with approximately the same thickness.
Before putting the new glass in place, finish scraping out the channel where the glass will go to make sure the glass seats against a nice flat surface.  Now is also a good time to prime the wood that is about to be covered up again.  Priming the wood will provide some level of protection to the wood to reduce rotting if water should get in.  You may want to add some sort of sealant to seal the glass to the frame to prevent air  getting through any gaps.  I don't normally work on windows of this type so I don't have a suggestion for what type of sealant, others may have ideas for that.
Once the glass in in place, replace the stops using whatever method of holding them in place was used previously.
Touch up paint until you are happy with the result.
Go get a beer and congratulate yourself on a job well done.  :)

An old windows, the glass is also likely to be held in with glazier's points and putty. There are various methods for trying to remove the putty, from heat guns to piloted router bits; if you can remove the putty without breaking the glass you then pry out the metal pieces (the points) holding the glass in place and if you are lucky it will lift free. Note that professionals tell me that even they break glass frequently when doing this, so be prepared for that.

The first wood stop/trim will probably need to be pry out at the centre to bend the wood enough to pass the corners/mitres.  Some will bend, some will crack.
